# C ReadProcessMemory - how to examine the memory area associated with a process

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I wans to read all of the memory associated with a particular process.  I am aware of ReadProcessMemory, but as I have little experience of using it and I am fearful that I will just get a load of rubbish out (rubbish in...).

a) how do I work out, from the base pointer to the end) the total region that I can read
b) what is the best way/safest to iterate over this area of memory and print it
c) how do I print it given that I don't know what values it will contain so that I can look at it?

I would also like to be able to include the actual location of each piece of data from within memory in my output.

Thanks R.

Comment: what types of memory are you wanting? the mapped .exe and .dlls? stack? heap? etc. what really are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Memory is accessible in units of pages (typically 4096 bytes).  If you read each page individually, you can know that if the read fails, that page is not readable and you can skip it.

```
#define PAGESIZE 4096
char *base = (char *)0;
do {

    char buffer[PAGESIZE];

    if (ReadProcessMemory(handle, base, buffer, PAGESIZE, NULL) != 0)
    {
        // buffer is valid

        // the address of buffer[X] is base+X
    }

    base += PAGESIZE;

// keep looping going until we wrap back around to 0
} while (base != 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Start with [VirtualQueryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366907(VS.85).aspx) to determine what parts of the process's address space have pages backing them up, then once you know what is where, you can use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553(VS.85).aspx) to look at the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you generally need (or at least want) to use to make much use of `ReadProcessMemory`. For your first question, finding blocks of memory that can be read, you can use `VirtualQueryEx` to find the regions of memory in a process, and how the virtual memory manager has marked each region.

To find things like locations of individual variables, you normally need to use the debugging API -- specifically the Symbol part -- `SymInitialize`, `SymGetSymFromName`, and possibly `SymEnumerateSymbols` should get you a decent start. There are quite a few more though...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jerry Coffin. This is just i was looking for
in winnt.h:

```
typedef struct _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION {
PVOID BaseAddress;
PVOID AllocationBase;
DWORD AllocationProtect;
DWORD RegionSize;
DWORD State;
DWORD Protect;
DWORD Type;
} MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

in winbase.h:

```
VirtualQueryEx(
HANDLE hProcess,
LPCVOID lpAddress,
PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer,
DWORD dwLength
);
```