# How can I access all bytes of RAM and ROM of my computer?

Tags: c++, c, memory

I tried pointers and reference(&) but when I try to get the info(I am only reading from memory) computer "beeps" and program terminates.
NO problem when assigning a pointer to a byte (char *). But when I read that computer beeps. ( x=*p;)

Windows xp, 1GB + 128 MB RAM. I don't know about my eproom + eeproms.

Can I use System() function to use OS commands to reach memory? Do you know any one?

Comment: IIRC: You can't, at least not without ring-0 access.

Comment: A question: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space

Comment: Remember that normal user-space programs are loaded into _virtual memory_ and therefore will never actually see the direct physical memory address space.

Comment: for asome anti-map-hacking in some games

Comment: I recommend you start from basics and read Ulrich Drepper's excellent "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory": http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: why would you need to access the computers ROMs for doing that?, just access the game's memory pages itself?!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [ReadProcessMemeory - How to examine the memory area associated with a process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330906/c-readprocessmemory-how-to-examine-the-memory-area-associated-with-a-process)

Comment: Tools do exist to do some of this http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Memory_Imaging ... I'd be surprised if there wasn't an existing driver you could install to allow you to get access to arbitrary bits of memory.

Comment: i wanted anti-hack(is another hack i know)

Comment: @Bo Persson : Yes that was what i want. Thank you. i will read about that page thing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't. Modern OSes use virtual mode and memory protection which don't permit this. To access all physical RAM, you'll most likely need to write your own OS or a kernel driver for an existing OS.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık If you choose to write your own OS, you will need to write some assembly code. If you choose to write a Windows kernel mode driver, you won't need to write any assembly code there.

Comment: I mean, that's the least. But you'll need to learn *way more* than that you know yet about computer and OS architecture :)

Comment: You could also get an old Apple ][ or similar :)

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this, because you have not privilege to do, when you run your code, it creates a process to run your program, and each process can only access to its address space, access to others process address space make a trap to os, and your kernel suspends works and checks your stack and your process, then it find that you did an unprivileged task, and then it kills your process

Answer (score 0):

This should help me:

```
typedef struct _MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION {
PVOID BaseAddress;
PVOID AllocationBase;
DWORD AllocationProtect;
DWORD RegionSize;
DWORD State;
DWORD Protect;
DWORD Type;
} MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, *PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
```

and this:

```
VirtualQueryEx(
HANDLE hProcess,
LPCVOID lpAddress,
PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer,
DWORD dwLength
);
```

at least in my OS
thanks Bo Persson and Jerry Coffin or Mysticial