# RAM browser with C programming language

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, volatile, ram

I want to browse a part of the **RAM**. I tried with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN ((volatile unsigned char*)0x00000000)
#define MAX ((volatile unsigned char*)0x0000ffff)


main()
{
    volatile char* c;
    for (c=MIN; c<MAX;c++) printf("c[%p]= %c\n",c,*c);
}
```

However the compiler display this message:

> warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast.

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: volatile unsigned char* c;

Comment: Also, what hardware/OS are you going to run this on?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but is what you are asking technically feasible? My understanding is that every application starts up with its own Virtual Address Space, so unless you do some special system call (or the like), can you even access memory outside what's been allocated to you by the memory manager?

Comment: @chronodekar - that's why I asked above.  On an embedded system, with no virtual memory manager, and RAM at those addresses, it should be OK.

Comment: @MartinJames embedded ... yes, I missed that. On the OMAP4 platform, I think the RAM range is from 0x80000000 to 0xBFFFFFFF. On another ARM system it would probably be something else. Just that when I read the question, I assumed the "application" would be running on a regular linux distro like ubuntu or some such.

Comment: @chronodekar - and it looks like your assumption was valid - OP now has segfault, as expected :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i access all bytes of RAM and ROM of my computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467292/how-can-i-access-all-bytes-of-ram-and-rom-of-my-computer)

Comment: @H2CO3:  It is not a duplicate of that, because here he is merely asking about the warning.

Answer (score 4):

`c` should have the same type as `MIM/MAX`: `volatile unsigned char* c;`.

Comment: I *think* I can understand how this would get rid of the compiler issue the OP has, but does it really help him/her read from RAM directly?

Comment: @chronodekar depends on his platform. It might do just that, or it might just try to read from his own process and possibly crash.

Comment: @nos which still leaves me stumped on _why_ this answer is getting so many upvotes ...

Comment: @chronodekar:  ... because it is the correct answer to the specific question asked (solving the problem of the warning).  He never asked about whether the code would work or even suggested that it did not.  On a bare-metal microcontroller, the code is entirely plausible (although the dereference of `c` when `c = 0x00000000` might cause a runtime error.

Comment: @Clifford _technically_ I can accept that it solves the direct question asked. But in light of the subject line, I'm uncomfortable with this answer. ... could just be me nitpicking.

Comment: @chronodekar:  In that case perhaps the criticism belongs with the question rather than the answer.  The question of "why am I getting this warning?" is not related to "RAM browser with C programming language" - its a poorly titled question - the application is not the cause of the warning.