# Is it possible to access DRAM bit cells using C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

Apologies if this is not the place to be asking this. I would like to know if the C programming language gives the user access to DRAM bit cells, I can't seem to find any resource online that specifically answer my question so I feel more inclined to assume this is not possible. Thanks

Comment: Whatever your hardware platform gives SW access to is accessible in C. C can access whatever memory addresses you wish, and it can access I/O ports as well, depending upon what your platform's C compiler tools enable.

Comment: Assuming you're not writing your own OS or kernel driver, then no. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467292/how-can-i-access-all-bytes-of-ram-and-rom-of-my-computer

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough to upvote your comments but just want to acknowledge your contribution with thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not give any specific means to directly read DRAM for standard hardware platforms: Windows, Linux, etc.
However, this is possible for certain embedded platforms, and heavily depends on the operating system, or kernel, or whatever is at the core of the system.

Embedded systems that are not under OSs with virtual memory, and that have direct memory access, obviously can and do access the memory.

Some of the systems have DMA, which allows Direct Memory Access, as the name said. For DMA, you got to have a code that programs DMA, and instructs it to read or write certain data from certain parts of the remote memory, in this case DRAM.

DRAM may be accessed directly if the hardware architecture supports it, and these days, this is not often the case, since it is considered that the DRAM access may slow the processor. That is why DMAs are used, to offload the main processor of the boring and tedious task of accessing external memory.

For example, see the following description of the code that tests the memory, and the primary thing is that the code can 'see' the DRAM memory directly:
https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf

To learn more about the memory, types of memory, and how to access the memory, please read the excellent article here:
https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Memory-Test-Suite-C

I hope that this answers your question, or at least helps you to understand what is involved in accessing DRAM. In a nutshell, OS accesses DRAM on usual systems, unless the system is designed in such a way, that DRAM may be accessed directly through the address.

Comment: Much better answer, and you even provided a paper to help with my research. Thanks VladP

Answer (score 0):

The C programming language can address memory, thus it can access DRAM bit cells. You have to know the address, the according DRAM bit is mapped to and use logic operators to manipulate the corresponding bit on that address.

Comment: The Q&A is now extremely misleading. For the most usual environments like Windows, Linux, macOS and even for your TV set-top box this answer is **wrong**.

Comment: My answer is as precise as the question was. Is it possible to access DRAM bits? This question is equivalent to "Is it possible to access RAM that is implemented with DRAM" Since the physical implementation of RAM has nothing to do with the program running on the system, my answer is quite valid.